# How do I pass a parameter to my Backbonejs Models' initialize-function when adding models via collection.push?

Tags: backbone.js, parameter-passing

so I've got the following problem here:

I've got a collection like this:

```
 MyApp.ArticleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        model: MyApp.ArticleModel,

        /**
         *  Fire func1-Event
         */
        func1: function () {
            ...
        }
    });
```

which is filled like this in an ajax call:

```
self.collection.push(articleFromService);
```

Now my Problem is: I need two different datasets when creating my model.

- Case A: It's a new article. It should have an Array of objects filled with every possible object (e.g. sizes from XS to XXXL or something similar, doesn't really matter).
- Case B: The Article needs to be edited alter on. In this case, the article has some chosen values for the Array (for the size-example: XS, L, XL) which i need to evaluate for pre-filling an editform.

So, this is my models' initialize-method so far:

```
         /**
         *  init Articlemodel
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this.dc = MyApp.DataCollector.getInstance(); //just a ring.js-class for caching data on clientside
                this.set('Sizes', this.dc.sizes != null ? this.dc.sizes : this.dc.getValuesFromArticleFilter()); //needed for there are different "standard sizes"-arrays. 
        },
```

But what I want to achieve is something like this, using a boolean-switch:

```
         /**
         *  init Articlemodel 
         */
        initialize: function (isEditMode) {
            this.dc = MyApp.DataCollector.getInstance();
            if (!isEditMode) {
                this.set('Sizes', this.dc.sizes != null ? this.dc.sizes : this.dc.getValuesFromArticleFilter());
            }
        },
```

So now I sadly have no idea how to pass the parameter `isEditMode` to every Model I initialize when I push it into my collection.

Comment: You should be able to pass a options object to `.push` and then that options object should in turn be passed to the `initialize` function of each created model.

Comment: so, i think i'm missing something obvious here, but... how do i pass it from the collection to the initialize-function of (each of) the model(s) created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass an options object to `.push` (or `.add`) the collection will pass that options object to each new model it creates.

Consider [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Fuu8AYKIA4UWCi2PZmk?p=preview)

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(attributes, options) {
    console.log(options.foo);
  }
});

var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Model
});

var myCollection = new Collection();
myCollection.push([
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 }
], { foo: 'bar' });
```

That code will log `bar` twice (once from the `initialize` of each model).

Armed with that knowledge, you can pass your `isEditMode` as an option to `self.collection.push(articleFromService);` and access it in the model's initialize the same way I accessed the `foo` option above.